# Sum of each item in For Loop

Tags: python

I'm a total beginner with Python/Django and this is probably a really easy thing to do, but i can't work out how.

I have a view that carries out some calculations within a `for loop` each loop creates a `"value":value` pair. I'm trying to add up all the values to create total.

```
for item in list:
    value = round(holding.price * price, 3)
    results.append({'value':value})

total = # How?
```

I've tried to loop through `results`, but I think because results is a list of dictionaries it doesn't work.

Is there an easy way?

Comment: What does `item` have to do with `value` and `price`?

Comment: Item is a list of items to loop through linked to holding price.

Comment: What is `results` before the loop?

Comment: But you don't do anything with `item` in your loop. You're going to end up with a list of identical values.

Comment: If requests for clarification are made in comments, address them by editing your question to clarify.

Comment: You need two things to happen 1) extract the value from each dictionary in the list, 2) sum over the extracted value.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to put the `value` properties into a list, and then sum that list:

```py
results = []
for item in lst:
    value = round(holding.price * price, 3)
    results.append({'value': value})

total = sum([dct['value'] for dct in results])
print(total)
```

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `total = len(lst) * round(holding.price * price, 3)`...